# Using case_when with mutate equivalent in python

Tags: python, r, pandas

I've just started with python and I'm trying to migrate some R functions I created over to python.
I am stumped by how to create a mutate column based on regex conditional.

**Aim**

I have a dataframe that contains text. I would like to extract the part of the text that refers to a score which contains the letter m followed by a digit eg 'm3' or 'M5' etc. The idea is that if the regex is present then the digit should be extracted in to a column called MStage.

The regex is a little complicated because of various edge cases so there are necessarily multiple regexes which have to be executed in order using an ifelse (or case_when) type clause.

**The R code looks like this:**

```
 dataframe <- dataframe %>%
    mutate(
      MStage = map(
        mytext, ~ case_when(
          grepl("(?<=\\d)\\s*[Mm](?:\\s|=)*\\d+", .x,perl = TRUE) ~ stringr::str_replace(stringr::str_extract(.x, "(?<=\\d)\\s*[Mm](?:\\s|=)*\\d+"), "M", ""),
          grepl("(?=[^\\.]*[Bb]arr)[^\\.]*\\s+\\d{2}\\s*[cm]*\\s*(to |-| and)\\s*\\d{2}\\s*[cm]*\\s*", .x, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE) ~ as.character(as.numeric(sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(stringr::str_extract(.x, "\\d{2}\\s*[cm]*\\s*(to|-|and)\\s*\\d{2}\\s*[cm]*\\s*"), "\\d{2}"), function(y) abs(diff(as.numeric(y)))))),
          grepl("(?=[^\\.]*cm)(?=[^\\.]*[Bb]arr)(?=[^\\.]*(of |length))[^\\.]*", .x, perl = TRUE) ~ stringr::str_extract(paste0(stringr::str_match(.x, "(?=[^\\.]*cm)(?=[^\\.]*[Bb]arr)(?=[^\\.]*(of |length))[^\\.]*"), collapse = ""), "\\d+"),
          grepl("(\\.|^|\n)(?=[^\\.]*(small|tiny|tongue|finger))(?=[^\\.]*[Bb]arr)[^\\.]*(\\.|\n|$)", .x, perl = TRUE) ~ stringr::str_replace(.x, ".*", "1"),
          TRUE ~ "Insufficient"
        )
      )
    )
```

**My attempt**

I have started to try to convert this into python with the following code:

```
df = df.assign(col = ['pos' if df['text'].str.contains('(?<=\\d)\\s*[Mm](?:\\s|=)*\\d+') else 'Insuf' ])
```

although the error I get is:

**The problem**

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'd like to be able to add the ability to extract the digit if the regex is true (as well as the other regexes as per the R code

Comment: I would just convert the case_when into a function that is a series of if/else statements and then apply that function to the 'text' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because `if` here is expecting a single boolean, but you're feeding it an entire series of booleans. Typically you can fix this by using a lambda function.

```
import re
pat = '(?<=\\d)\\s*[Mm](?:\\s|=)*\\d+'
df = df.assign(col = lambda x: 'pos' if re.search(pat, x) else 'Insuf')
```

To extract the digit, just use a different `re` method (probably `re.match()` if you just need the first occurance) en lieu of the `'pos'`, or replace the `if else` with the `re.match()` and `fillna()` with `'Insuf'` on the other side of the `assign()`.

```
df = df.assign(col = lambda x: re.match(pat, x)).fillna(value='Insuf')
```